# how to select sum limit to X number mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = "SELECT sum(DAILYTIME)  FROM $mytable  LIMIT 5";
```

that statement selects and sums limited to 5 rows, but how to do it based on certain row. For example I want to use row #10 as a starting point and sum 5 rows below that one ( 5 rows including that same row ).

how would the statement need to be, because if i do `WHERE  DAY = '$day' LIMIT 5` 
it will not sum all the 5 rows, just 1

Comment: Try adding  `GROUP BY DAILYTIME` before LIMIT, should work. Or use a subquery. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html

Comment: LIMIT can also handle an extra parameter. I.e.: `LIMIT 5,10`

Comment: LIMIT is irrelevant for what is wanted; in this context it would only mean you'll get back no more than 5 totals based on your GROUPing criteria, which (since there is none) would only result in one row to begin with.

Comment: an answer's been given below. take it up with them. If that doesn't work, I'll come up with a solution for you. Unless you stick with them and tell them why it didn't work for you and they should improve on their answer.

Comment: @Uueerdo you're more than welcome to submit an answer seeing you know what this involves and how it should be done. The OP can choose from either one given. The example I've given the OP for LIMIT, was merely an example. I've no idea if the OP saw the answer below, and if it worked or not. My doing up code and testing it, would probably be a waste of time. The OP can always call me out and ask: *"Sure Fred, I'll wait to see your answer"* ;-)

Comment: Fred ty for that useful link,

Comment: You're welcome @nonaxanon glad to see you found your solution, *cheers*

Comment: its people like you guys that make me keep wanting on doing stuff, people like you who are willing to help not asking anything in return, wish so much more persons were like you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding a where clause with the `>=` operator, you will also select all following rows. Use the following query:

```
$query = "SELECT sum(DAILYTIME) FROM $mytable WHERE DAY >= '$day' LIMIT 5";
```

Comment: I'm always open for that ;-)

Comment: The LIMIT clause on this query is superfluous. The query returns at most one row, and the LIMIT clause doesn't have any effect on the value returned by the aggregate.  (The only way the `LIMIT` would have an affect is if we were to specify `LIMIT 0`, or `LIMIT m,n` (m>0), so no row was returned.)

Comment: That query is going to give the total for all days after or on $day, not limit it to summing 5 records on or after that value.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the sum of the 10th through 14th "rows"; however, since there is no `ORDER BY`, there is no guarantee which rows of the table the result rows of the subquery would be.

```
SELECT sum(DAILYTIME) 
FROM (
    SELECT DAILYTIME 
    FROM $mytable 
    LIMIT 9, 5
  ) AS `rows10to15`
;
```